# Inlining SVG code not displaying svg icon

Tags: html, css, svg

Intuitively I feel this is possible but after googling around I am still not getting the expected outcome of displaying the custom svg icon.

Expected outcome: rendering `<li>` bullet points with a custom svg icon, where the svg code is "defined" in the `<head>` section and *ideally* not defined in its own svg file.

Current outcome: No bullet point displays, either custom or "default"

Code sample:

```
<!--HTML file -->
<head>

<!--
 ...other head stuff here...
-->

<!--Testing SVG embed-->
        <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M7 10L9 12L13 8M19 10C19 14.9706 14.9706 19 10 19C5.02944 19 1 14.9706 1 10C1 5.02944 5.02944 1 10 1C14.9706 1 19 5.02944 19 10Z" stroke="#96D8A0" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            <!--I think use the xlink:href attrib to make the svg 'referencable'?? -->
            <use xlink:href="item-checkbox@18.svg"></use>
        </svg>
</head>
```

```
/*.css file*/

/* class controlling <li> element styling */

.checkbox-items li{
    list-style-image: url("/item-checkbox18.svg");
}
```

However, nothing displays with this approach. The checkbox items **do** display when I am serving them thru a CDN, but ideally the SVGs are rendered in the document itself so fewer things to load externally.

Comment: I suspect the use tag isn't doing quite what you expect, see [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this which prevents there being a 'extra' SVG in the DOM is to inline it. That way your styling is completely within your CSS.

There are different converters out there, I just used the first one I came across.

```css
.checkbox-items li{
    list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M7 10L9 12L13 8M19 10C19 14.9706 14.9706 19 10 19C5.02944 19 1 14.9706 1 10C1 5.02944 5.02944 1 10 1C14.9706 1 19 5.02944 19 10Z' stroke='%2396D8A0' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

```html
<ul class="checkbox-items">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```