# Vertically aligning custom svg list item bullet points with text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have created a custom SVG bullet point icon per the suggested answer in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68494111/inlining-svg-code-not-displaying-svg-icon?noredirect=1#comment121050655_68494111) and now I am trying to "vertically align" the `li` bullet point such that it is vertically centered with the item text.

Here is the **current** outcome displaying the list with the custom svg bullet points:

[image: bullet points are way too high up]

Expected outcome: bullet point icons are "middle aligned" with each `li`'s text

I have tried multiple permutations of how to do this, notably referencing code from [here](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-do-i-vertically-align-custom-bullets-to-the-middle-of-the-list-content/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342788/vertically-align-smaller-bullets-with-larger-text), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179566/how-do-i-vertically-align-my-list-items-with-the-bullets) and in each attempted case, when I refresh the page (local file) for the changes, the SVG bullets are no longer visible in the list. (they're not visible anywhere on the page)

Here is a sample of what I have tried:

HTML layout:

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class = "list-section">
<ul>
    <li>This is my first list item, padded out for double line test!</li>
    <li>This is the second list item, also suitably padded out for testing</li>
    <li>Third item list, about same level of padding!</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Attempt 1

```
li.list-section:before{
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M7 10L9 12L13 8M19 10C19 14.9706 14.9706 19 10 19C5.02944 19 1 14.9706 1 10C1 5.02944 5.02944 1 10 1C14.9706 1 19 5.02944 19 10Z' stroke='%2396D8A0' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:-10px;
}

.list-section li{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6D6D6D;
    margin: 16px 0px;
```

Attempt 2

```
.list-section li{
    list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 20 20' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M7 10L9 12L13 8M19 10C19 14.9706 14.9706 19 10 19C5.02944 19 1 14.9706 1 10C1 5.02944 5.02944 1 10 1C14.9706 1 19 5.02944 19 10Z' stroke='%2396D8A0' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6D6D6D;
    margin: 16px 0px;
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your train of thought is correct. Only the code contains typos.

If I understand correctly, then the result should be as follows (*run the snippet and resize the block by grabbing it by the lower right corner*):

- **With flex and transform**

```css
.main-container {
/* For example only */ resize: both; overflow: scroll; min-height: 100px; min-width: 100px;
}

.list-section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-section ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6D6D6D;
}
.list-section ul li::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M7 10L9 12L13 8M19 10C19 15 15 19 10 19C5 19 1 15 1 10C1 5 5 1 10 1C15 1 19 5 19 10Z' stroke='%2396D8A0' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  height: 20px; width: 20px;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="list-section">
    <ul>
      <li>This is my first list item, padded out for double line test!</li>
      <li>This is the second list item, also suitably padded out for testing</li>
      <li>Third item list, about same level of padding!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

- **With position and transform**

```css
.main-container { /* For example only */ resize: both; overflow: scroll; min-height: 100px; min-width: 100px; }

.list-section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-section ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6D6D6D;
}
.list-section ul li::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M7 10L9 12L13 8M19 10C19 15 15 19 10 19C5 19 1 15 1 10C1 5 5 1 10 1C15 1 19 5 19 10Z' stroke='%2396D8A0' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 0;
  height: 20px; width: 20px;
  transform: translate(-150%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="list-section">
    <ul>
      <li>This is my first list item, padded out for double line test!</li>
      <li>This is the second list item, also suitably padded out for testing</li>
      <li>Third item list, about same level of padding!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: legend! This was exactly what I needed, thanks! I'm trying to form a mental model around this: does the `ul li{}` property `margin` need a value in *em* units? Why assign the `margin` property a 0 value?

Comment: @GPP: The amount of indentation between list items specified in "em" allows them to change proportionally, depending on the font size. The list box `<ul>` has margins by default, so we set them to zero (optional).

Comment: got it thanks! So what would you say are the "crucial" properties that produced the expected outcome of the vertically centered svg bullet points?

Comment: If you look carefully this doesn't align vertically center; more pronounced with larger font sizes

Comment: @alias51: Corrected.